# How to get media URL while Integration WhatsApp with IBM Watson

Tags: twilio, ibm-cloud

I'm working on a scenario to get image URL from WhatsApp to IBM Watson. How can I get the URL of the media from WhatsApp(Twilio) to IBM using webhook.

Twilio logs the media message as shown in attachment.

[image]

At least can we get all these message details from Twilio to IBM, so that I can use the message id to get the media URL.

I'm not clear how can I make a proper integration to get the WhatsApp image URL reflects in IBM Watson.

The body of the image is name of the file. How can I get the media URL from this to IBM?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio stores the sent media files in a cloud storage and attached the URL(s) to the payload of webhook request. The parameters are named `MediaUrlX`, where X is a zero-based index. So, for example, the URL for the first media attachment will be in the `MediaUrl0` parameter, the second in `MediaUrl1`, and so on.

Please also note this important note from the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/api):

> Supported media include images (JPG, JPEG, PNG), audio files, and PDF files, with a size limit of 16MB per message.

You should also be able to see the sent media file in the log if it has been received successfully:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @IObert for your response. I was looking into a scenario, where I will be sending an Image to IBM Watson via WhatsApp Channel using Twilio integration. So can you explain me a bit detail, how the Twilio send the message id or media URL to IBM?

Comment: I don't really know how to Watson API works and what it expected. With the URL returned from the Twilio webhook, you can do anything. Either you just pass the URL to Watson, or you download the image and sent this one to Watson then.